# combining mutiple security configurations

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I am currently working on a spring boot project that has multiple security (authentication) configurations combined:

1. a rest api with http basic auth
2. a rest api with jwt auth.
3. a web (form login) with 2fa auth.

The problem I am experiencing is, that the configurations cannot be entirely seperated. More specific: The authenticiation providers are accumulated (in the provider manager), which prevents my preferred setup from working correctly.

What happens is this: In config (3) i have a custom 2fa authentication provider which checks if the credentials (both password and 2FA code!) are entered correctly. If the password is correct, but the 2fa code is not, it exits (catches) with a (authentication or bad credentials) exception. However, as it exits the 2fa authentication provider, it goes back to the provider manager. The latter has another (DAO) auth provider at hand, and checks the credentials again: but this time: only password! not the 2fa code!). As the password is ok, it authorized the request.

So for short: I am experiencing a problem where the first authentication provider does NOT authorize, but the second does (because that one does not take the 2fa code into account)!
I have been at this for days, and i cannot seem to get this right.
As an alternative i have now opted for a solution using a 2fa custom filter. But is not my preferred solution, as it gives me some frontend problems (i first have to authorize the username/password, and only after that i can check the 2fa code).

Is there a solution using my 2fa auth provider? I would sort of wish that the auth providers would not get accumulated, so that when the first auth. provider exits with bad credentials, the auth procedure ends with a 'bad credentials'.

My config class:

```
WebSecurityConfig.java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class WebSecurityConfig_backup extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private HttpBasicAuthenticationExceptionHandler authenticationExceptionHandler;
    private JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider;
    private MfaAuthenticationDetailsSource mfaAuthenticationDetailsSource;
    private MfaAuthenticationProvider2 mfaAuthenticationProvider;

      @Bean
      @Override
      public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
      }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public class ApiV1WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.antMatcher("/api/v1/**")
                    .httpBasic()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationExceptionHandler)
                    .and()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests(authorize -> {
                        authorize
                                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,
                                        "/api/v1/transaction/**").hasAnyRole("BANK", "ADMIN")
                                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,
                                        "/api/v1/transaction/**").hasAnyRole("BANK", "ADMIN");
                        //.anyRequest().denyAll();
                    })
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        }


        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth   .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        }


    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public class ApiV2WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.antMatcher("/api/v2/**")
                    .addFilter(bearerTokenAuthenticationFilter())
                    .addFilter(credentialsAuthenticationFilter())
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests(authorize -> {
                        authorize
                                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,
                                        "/api/v2/transaction/**").hasAnyRole("BANK", "ADMIN")
                                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,
                                        "/api/v2/transaction/**").hasAnyRole("BANK", "ADMIN");
                        //.anyRequest().denyAll();
                    })
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .and()
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        }

        private BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter bearerTokenAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
            BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter filter = new BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
            filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());

            return filter;
        }

        private CredentialsAuthenticationFilter credentialsAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
            CredentialsAuthenticationFilter filter = new CredentialsAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
            filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());

            return filter;
        }

        private AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
            return (request, response, ex) -> {
                response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
                response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
                response.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName());

                ResponseWriterUtil.writeErrorResponse(response, ex.getMessage());
            };
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(jwtAuthenticationProvider)
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(3)
    public class FormWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            //authorisation
            http//.addFilterBefore(googleTfaFilter, SessionManagementFilter.class)
                    .authorizeRequests(authorize -> {
                        authorize
                                .mvcMatchers("/", "/login", "/logout", "/registrationPage", "/register").permitAll()
                                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,
                                        "/others1", "/others2").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,
                                        "/others1", "/others2").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN");
                    })
                    .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                        .usernameParameter("email")
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                        .failureUrl("/login?error")
                        .authenticationDetailsSource(mfaAuthenticationDetailsSource)
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "GET"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionFixation().migrateSession()
                    .and()
                    .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()
                    .and()
                    .csrf();

        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/lib/**");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(mfaAuthenticationProvider)
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        }
    }
}
```

auth provider for config 2:

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(BearerTokenAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        BearerTokenAuthenticationToken bearerToken = (BearerTokenAuthenticationToken) authentication;
        Authentication auth = null;

        try {
            //validate the token
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(JWT_TOKEN_SECRET).parseClaimsJws(bearerToken.getToken());
            
            JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil = new JwtTokenUtil(bearerToken.getToken());
            String username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken();
            
            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());            
            log.debug("Authentication token: " + auth);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new UserServiceAuthenticationException("Invalid token");
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            throw new UserServiceAuthenticationException("Token expired");
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            throw new UserServiceAuthenticationException("Invalid signature");
        }
        
        return auth;
    }
}
```

Auth provider for config (3)

```
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
public class MfaAuthenticationProvider2 implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private UserRepo userRepository;
    private GoogleAuthenticator googleAuthenticator;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        String verficationCode = ((MfaAuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails()).getUserMFaCode();
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(authentication.getName()).stream().findFirst().orElse(null);

        if(user == null || !passwordEncoder.matches(password, user.getPassword())){
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username or password");
        }

        try {

            if(!googleAuthenticator.authorizeUser(user.getUsername(), Integer.parseInt(verficationCode))){
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid verification code.");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Authentication failed. Please try again.");
        }

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, user.getAuthorities());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

}
```

My current alternative solution for config 3:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class GoogleTfaFilter2 extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final AuthenticationTrustResolver authenticationTrustResolver = new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();
    private final GoogleTfaFailureHandler googleTfaFailureHandler = new GoogleTfaFailureHandler();
    private final RequestMatcher urlIs2fa = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/verify2fa");
    private final RequestMatcher urlIs2fa2 = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/register2fa");
    private final RequestMatcher urlResource = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/resources/**");
    private final RequestMatcher api = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**");

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        StaticResourceRequest.StaticResourceRequestMatcher staticResourceRequestMatcher =
                PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations();

        if (urlIs2fa.matches(request) || urlResource.matches(request) || urlIs2fa2.matches(request)||
                staticResourceRequestMatcher.matcher(request).isMatch() || api.matches(request)) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication != null  && !authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication)){
            log.debug("Processing 2FA Filter");

            if (authentication.getPrincipal() != null && authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof User) {
                User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();

                if (!user.getMfaPassed()) {
                    log.debug("2FA Required");

                    request.getRequestDispatcher("/verify2fa").forward(request, response);
                    return;
                }

            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: This seems like a good candidate for breaking things up into "microservices"

Comment: as soon as you use custom filters, all bets are off. Then you need to exclude and handle a lot things manually. I have NO IDEA why you have for instance written a custom JWT filter, when the framework already contains one. Whats the point of using a security framework, if you insist on not using the framework and instead write a bunch of custom security, which i might add is bad practice. Custom security is ALWAYS bad practice

Comment: Well, i will take your word for it. Although the JWT part is not using the custom filter, the 2FA config does that.  Also, all 3 configurations are taken from experts (tutors and other profs publishing on www). I just combines all 3.  And I can believe it be approved upon, but cannot believe any of them would contain 'dumn' things.

Comment: were they come from is not the point, santa clause could have given them to you (but then i might add that santa clause is teaching bad practices). There are standards within security. You might add the perfect security solutions, but remember that any custom security only needs one bug now or in any future, to compromise the entire application and its data. Spring security is open source, fully tested and run in 10 000 applications around the world. They follow standards, and are reviewed by 100s of developers. And you selected to not use it.

Comment: for instance, there is already a fully implemented JWTAuthenticationProvider https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/authentication/JwtAuthenticationProvider.html

Comment: I see. It would make sense to use this. I have been searching for JWT implementations. All of them use filters or other means to seperate the token from the username/password.  None of the implementations i have seen use the provider you mention. Can you point out any example implementations that I can have a look at?

Comment: just go to the spring security reference documentation, and read the JWT chapter. Always start by reading the official documentation, never trust blogs.

Comment: I'm most likely the dummest person here, but the documentation didn't do it for me. In all implementations I see around (even resources like tutorialspoint), the Jwt projects are build alike what I have done (copied).